# Use Array Variable (Out from Execute Immediate) in Select statement in store procedurce

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I need to use Array Variable (out from Execute Immediate) as Parameter in Select Statement in Store Procedure.

Create new type as Varray (As Below code)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Array_LIST AS VARRAY(200) OF VARCHAR2(10);
```

Then Create my procedure that return table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SchemaName.ProcedureName
(Query_String IN VARCHAR2, Ref_Cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)

AS
BEGIN
DECLARE COMCODE Array_LIST;

    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Query_String BULK COLLECT INTO COMCODE;

            BEGIN
                    Open Ref_Cursor For

                        SELECT
                             Column1, Column2
                        From Table_Name
                        Where
                            Column1 IN (COMCODE);
            END;
    END;
END;
```

When I executed this procedure, I got below error

```
==> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes : expected NUMBER got Scheman_Name.Array_LIST
```

Can anyone help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just a small problem in the use of a collection type in a SQL `IN` clause.  Using a collection type directly in an `IN` clause is not supported.  Collection types need to be `TABLE`d for use in SQL.

Here's a slight modification that compiles and executes ok:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME(COLUMN1 VARCHAR2(32), COLUMN2 VARCHAR2(32));

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Array_LIST AS VARRAY(200) OF VARCHAR2(10);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ProcedureName
(Query_String IN VARCHAR2, Ref_Cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)

AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE COMCODE Array_LIST;

  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE Query_String BULK COLLECT INTO COMCODE;

    BEGIN
      Open Ref_Cursor For

        SELECT
          Column1, Column2
        From Table_Name
        Where
            Column1 IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(COMCODE));
    END;
  END;
END;
/

Procedure created.
```

Then it will execute ok:

```
DECLARE
V_CURSOR SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  PROCEDURENAME(Q'!SELECT 'LOREM IPSUM' FROM DUAL!',V_CURSOR);
END;
/


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```